# Fuzzy logic with account name

Tags: apex

I have a requirement where I need to read an input csv file which has a column called account name and needs to query the account object with a name match. Now the account name field on the csv file can have company names like the following combination:

- Langan Engineering & Environmental Service
- Langan Engineering & Environmental Services, Inc.
- Langan Engineering & Environmental Svs.
- Langan Engineering And Environmental Services

or:

- Matrix New World Engineering
- Matrix New World Engineering Inc.
- Matrix New World Engineering, Inc

The goal is to match these combinations on the csv file and query the account object for a name match and find out if the records exist or not. Has anybody done any fuzzy logic matching on account names and if so can you share some code snippets?

Comment: Why do you need fuzzy search? You could certainly look at those examples and come up with a fuzzy search that works, but automating that is more complicated than just adding all the names you want to match to a collection and filtering on that.

Answer (score 1):

It's not AI-levels of fuzzy matching, but a fairly simple method which can still be done with efficient querying is to decide on a canonical representation of the company names; then do your searching using that.

Looking at your examples, we could say that Matrix New World Engineering would be the canonical result from all the variations you listed. To get from any of the variations you have to that, you'll be doing things like:

- Removing Inc, Plc, and punctuation
- Turning & into And
- Changing abbreviations
- Anything else you want to do

You can create a Canonical_Name__c field on Account in SF, write some batch Apex and/or trigger to set Canonical_Name__c from Name.

Then apply the same logic to get the canonical name from your CSV data.

Then, the matching is an exact match using SOQL on Canonical_Name__c.

If you need more complex matching and can live with it running as a really slow batch, you could start looking at getLevenshteinDistance() on the String class, but that still doesn't do a great job and would take a lot of processing on the database to work with.